# Change the cursor when the mouse's over the intersection area of 2 panels

Tags: java, swing, panel

I have 2 Jpanel (leftpanel and rightpanel) on JFrame. How can I change the cursor when the mouse's over the intersection area of 2 panels?

[image]

So far, i tried :

```
 ...
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
           if (leftpanel.contains(e.getPoint()) && rightpanel.contains(e.getPoint())){

                frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR));

          }
           else{ frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        };
```

but it was not working..

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to resize, you may consider using a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) to handle this for you.

Comment: If `leftpanel` and `rightpanel` are disjoint, how can the first predicate ever be true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question was how to detect the intersection of two panels and change the cursor. Here is an example of how to do that

```
    public static void overlapTest() {
        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        p2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        final JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(null);
        container.add(p1);
        container.add(p2);
        p1.setBounds(0,0,120,100);
        p2.setBounds(80,0,120,100);
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200,100);
        container.setPreferredSize(size);
        container.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                Point pt1 = e.getPoint();
                pt1.translate(-p1.getX(), -p1.getY());
                Point pt2 = e.getPoint(); 
                pt2.translate(-p2.getX(), -p2.getY());
                if (p1.contains(pt1) && p2.contains(pt2)) {
                        System.out.println("both contain: " + e.getPoint());
                        container.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                  }
                  else{ 
                      container.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                  };
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems that I have answered the question that was asked, but not what was desired...

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffey's suggestion, I should use JSlitPane to handle.